# storing drop down select data in a local storage using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and have been having some issues with storing data in a local storage. I want to store a form data in a JSON object so that the records are appended in an object array and can be saved in a local storage. But everytime the log displays an error while retrieving the value of a select element. Here's the code:

```
home.html

<form id="form" onsubmit="submit();">
    <h3 align="center" >Contact Form</h3>

    <table align="center" cellspacing="3dp" cellpadding="20dp">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" required align="center" size="20dp" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" required align="center" size="20dp" id="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Contact No.:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" required align="center" size="20dp" id="contact"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Gender:</label></td>
            <td><select name="gender" id="gender">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Comments</label></td>
            <td><textarea id="comment"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><br></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" align="center"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the js:

```
main.js
function submit()
{
var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('records'))||[];
var newData =
[{
    'name': document.getElementById("name"),
    'email': document.getElementById("email"),
    'contact': document.getElementById("contact"),
    'gender': document.getElementById("gender"),
    'comment':document.getElementById("comment")
}];
myData.push(newData);
localStorage.setItem("records", JSON.stringify(myData));

var newData1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("records"));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the error though?

Comment: Thats what i'm trying to figure out. everytime the submit action rewrites the url with:
http://localhost:63342/home.html?gender=Male

Comment: you can not link your localhost pages here

Comment: i'll keep that in mind. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to have a look at this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oyxyrb6m/)

problem with your code is your that you storing `DOM elements` in the object rather than value of `elements`

i changed this function

```
var newData =
[{
    'name': document.getElementById("name").value,
    'email': document.getElementById("email").value,
    'contact': document.getElementById("contact").value,
    'gender': document.getElementById("gender").value,
    'comment':document.getElementById("comment").value
}];
```

Comment: fiddle.jshell.net/siddarthvader/f7e8rLqt/show/:60 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
fiddle.jshell.net/:60 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input